# Primefaces TabView responsiveness

Tags: jsf, primefaces, responsive-design, tabview

I'm using [primefaces 5.3](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces) and I want to use [primefaces' tabView](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/tabView.xhtml).

In primefaces showcase the component seems to be responsive, but in my code seems to be not.
[[image: tabView not responsive]]

Question 1: Am I using older version than primefaces official site does? This is the latest I could find.

Question 2: How could I make it responsive myself?

The only I could think for this is using [panelGrid](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml) but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Q1: check how and what PrimeFaces releaswes. And Check the bottom of the showcase. Q2: by learning how responsiveness is achieved in general and then applying that knowledge to the PrimeFaces generated html and/or source (looking at the source in trunk/main in github might help)

Comment: You are right, I was just being afraid not be downvoted again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem with CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 810px) {
    .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-top > .ui-tabs-nav li{
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```